# Nullify a variable in service

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a smart component `book-smart` that will display `book-update` if there is a `BookDto` in my `book.service` or `book-create` if it's empty.
The user access the update part by clicking on a button in a table, and the create by clicking on a button in the navbar.

With the current behavior, when my user click on the update button and then on the create button, it's still displaying the update as there is still a book in my service.

In my smart component, I tried to nullify the variable:
`this.bookService.book = null` -> resulting in an error: `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'BookDto'.`

Here are my classes:

```
export class BookSmartComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private bookService: BookService) { }
  book!: BookDto;

  ngOnInit(): void {
    if(this.bookService.book) {
      this.book = this.bookService.book;
      this.bookService.book = null // Error
    }
  }
}
```

`book-smart.component.html`

```html
<sandbox-book-insert [hidden]="book"></sandbox-book-insert>
<sandbox-book-update [hidden]="!book"  [book]="book"></sandbox-book-update>
```

`book.service.ts`

```
export class BookService {
 book!: BookDto;

 constructor() {}
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare variable in service as below and it will not give you error

```
book!: BookDto | null;
```

Comment: The bang (`!`) means it can't be null, but then you allow nulls explicitly. Instead just use `book?: BookDto`

Comment: Thank you @Abhishek this solution works. @aviad-p your solution still gives `Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'BookDto | undefined'`. I believe (`?`) still doesn't allow nulls. But now that you say that (`!`) doesn't allow null, I feel like this is a bit of non-sense to write `book!: BookDto | null;`. But I don't see any other way to do it as I do not want to `= new BookDto()`

Comment: The `?` means `undefined`. So just change the type to `book: BookDto | null = null` to initialize it with `null`.

Answer (score 2):

The exclamation mark after the property means that this property can't be assigned `null` or `undefined` value. If you want it to be nullable, simply remove the postfix exclamation mark in your `BookService`, i.e.

```
book: BookDto;
```

This will allow assigning `null` value to the property.

Also note that this depends on your compiler options. If you use the `--strictNullChecks` flag in your tsconfig, this will not work and you will have to allow assigning those values manually, i.e.

```
book: BookDto | null | undefined;
```

This is the proper way to  do it, as you can read in the official [typescript docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#null-and-undefined).

Comment: Yes, when I remove the exclamation mark, I get this: `Property 'book' has no initializer and is not definitely assigned in the constructor.`. That being said, I could just use the flag you mentioned but I can't tell if it's a good/bad practice. What do you think? Thank you